# onCreateOptionMenu method is not called in fragment android

Tags: android

Here, It is my java file named `Home1`

```
public class Home1 extends SherlockFragment 
{


public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dashboard, container, false);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    myevents = new ArrayList<Myevent>();
    myevents_searchable = new ArrayList<Myevent>();
    listview = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.events);
    Button btn=(Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.create_new_tkt);
    btn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    loginaync = new LoginAsync();
    loginaync.execute((Void) null);
    listview.setOnItemClickListener(listener);


    return rootView;

}


public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (loading != null)
    {
        if(loading.isShowing())
        {
            loading.dismiss();
        }
    }
}



public void onCreateOptionMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater)
{
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    Log.e("hii_onoptionmenu","Test");
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);


    MenuItem menuitem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_refresh);
    menuitem.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new OnMenuItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            loginaync = null;
            loginaync = new LoginAsync();
            loginaync.execute((Void) null);
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

Here, as you can see, I have extended `SherlockFragment` and I am trying to implement menu also. But `onCreateOptionMenu()` method is not called. What is the problem over here? Why this method is not called? Please Help.

Comment: Try this, write @override notation and inside the method call super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater); as the last statement.

Answer (score 0):

Please check that you override

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu menu, com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuInflater inflater) {
}
```

**AND NOT**

```
@Override
public final void onCreateOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu menu, android.view.MenuInflater inflater) {
}
```

Argument types are different (from different packages).

Comment: The superclass SherlockFragment only allows you to override the method with the correct arguments. It has a 'final' keyword' for incorrect methods to prevent overriding. Please check the code here: https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/blob/master/actionbarsherlock/src/com/actionbarsherlock/app/SherlockFragment.java

Answer (score 0):

I found my solution.

```
public class Home1 extends SherlockFragment implements OnCreateOptionsMenuListener
```

{

```
}
```

I have implemented OnCreateOptionsMenuListener in my class. It overrides that method. once method is overridden, then you can remove implementation of OnCreateOptionsMenuListener. Thanks for your suggestions.